# Is every complete Boolean algebra isomorphic to the quotient of a powerset algebra?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, boolean-algebras

Is every complete Boolean algebra isomorphic to a quotient, as a Boolean algebra, of some powerset algebra $\wp(X)$?

It is not true for arbitrary Boolean algebras, see the comments, or see [my MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2859214/is-every-boolean-algebra-isomorphic-to-the-quotient-of-a-powerset-algebra).

---

I am also aware of the **Loomis-Sikorski Theorem**: Every $\sigma$-complete Boolean algebra is isomorphic to the a quotient $\mathbf{F}/\mathcal{I}$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is a $σ$-field of sets and $\mathcal{I}\subseteq\mathbf{F}$ is a $\sigma$-ideal. So this can be viewed as asking whether there is an equivalent theorem for complete Boolean algebras.

Comment: This is cross-posted to Math.SE and indeed more appropriate there, so I move my answer to a comment and vote to close. A free algebra on an infinite set is not complete (exercise). If it would be a quotient of a powerset it would be a retract of it (exercise), and a retract of a complete algebra is complete (exercise).

Comment: The Cantor set is not homeomorphic to a closed subset of a Stone-Cech compactification of a discrete set (since any converging sequence therein is eventually constant). By Stone duality, this reflects in the fact that the corresponding Boolean algebra is not quotient of a power set (@მამუკაჯიბლაძე 's argument yields something more general but I wanted to point out this topological interpretation).

Comment: Link to MathSE post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2859214/is-every-boolean-algebra-isomorphic-to-the-quotient-of-a-powerset-algebra

Comment: @YCor I believe my argument is not really more general but rather sort of "Stone dual" to yours...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It's more general because I restricted to the Cantor set, i.e. to the countable free Boolean algebra, and also because your argument probably applies to many other non-free algebras.

Comment: @YCor Well it works also for generalized cantors, i. e. arbitrary powers of the two point discrete space, which is Stone dual to a free BA. It would apply to projective BAs but I think they are all free? Or not?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე That’s fine—then the question remains. Are all complete Boolean algebras isomorphic to quotients of powerset algebras?

Comment: Again no, and there is an even simpler argument that would work for your previous question too: image of an atom under a surjective homomorphism is either 0 or an atom. There are atomless complete Boolean algebras (e. g. regular closed sets of nice spaces without isolated points); and the free one is also atomless (although not complete).

Comment: Okay, complete atomic Boolean algebras are simply isomorphic to powerset algebras. That is rather dull. If $\mathbb{B}$ is complete and atomfree, why is an epimorphism from an atomic algebra impossible? The epimorphism doesn't have to be a morphism in the category CBA, but just in BA.

Comment: @Thomas: ${\mathcal P}(\omega)/\textrm{fin}$ is an atomless quotient of a power set algebra.

Comment: yes, I know. The question is whether _**all**_ (complete) BAs are isomorphic in the category BA to a quotient of a powerset algebra, not whether one exists.

Comment: (I should have written the 2nd last comment in the conjunctive. I wasn't admitting to this being impossible, but was working with the claim of მამუკაჯიბლაძე. His claim is correct in the category cBA, but clearly not in BA—as your example demonstrates.)

Comment: @Thomas: My point is that ${\mathcal P}(\omega)/\textrm{fin}$ is neither complete nor atomic, yet it is a quotient of a power set algebra. Thus, the suggestions made above that quotients of power set algebras should be complete and/or atomic are not correct.

Comment: I've edited to take into account the discussion and the fact that the original question is possibly off-topic and already answered on the MathSE crosspost.

Comment: Yes my claim is wrong and I expanded on it in the Math.SE answer. This is one illustration why crossposting is not good - it introduces confusion and doubles everything unnecessarily. Sorry.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე why on Earth are there two websites on SE for maths anyway? That adds to the confusion. I only posted twice, because I, after having previously posted a question and not recieved any reponses and after noticing there were two sites, thought that it was down to this, and that I would better my odds at gaining a reply by posting on both. If this is an issue, why not have an automated mechanism, that collapses doubled questions or that shuts one thread down and forwards to the other?

Comment: This site is for research level questions. As it happens, yours was borderline: the question without completeness requirement was more like not research level while with it it is more like research level. You can post your suggestion on meta although I don't think such automation is easy to implement. Btw changing the content of the question also adds to confusion

Comment: there’s wasn't any serious change of content, only specification.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This variation of the question comes from the comments on the original question.

**The question is whether all (complete) BAs are isomorphic in the category BA to a quotient of a powerset algebra.**

---

The Sikorski extension theorem guarantees that every complete BA is a quotient of a power set algebra.

**The Theorem.** (Sikorski) Let $A$ be a subalgebra of a Boolean algebra $B$, and let $f:A\to C$ be a homomorphism from $A$ to a complete Boolean algebra $C$. Then $f$ can be extended to a homomorphism $\widehat{f}:B\to C$.

**Application.** Let $A=C$ be a complete Boolean algebra, and represent it as a subalgebra of a power set BA $B={\mathcal P}(X)$. (Use Stone duality or Birkhoff's subdirect representation theorem for this.) The Sikorski theorem guarantees that that the identity function ${\sf id}\colon A=C\to C$ can be extended to a homomorphism $\widehat{\sf{id}}: B={\mathcal P}(X)\to C$. Since $\widehat{\sf id}$ extends the identity function, it is surjective. \\\

This argument shows that any complete BA is in fact a retract of a power set BA. The converse is easily seen to be true, so the class of complete BA's is exactly the class of retracts of power set BA's.

---

Also, from the comments on the original question:

There are incomplete BA's that are quotients of power set BA's. E.g. ${\mathcal P}(\omega)/\textrm{fin}$.

Infinite free BA's are not quotients of power set algebras.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I’m looking for. I have now found a side reference to this in my book on set theory.